# How can I select random verts, not faces

Tags: selection-tools

I want to select random verts for something in blender, but every time I try to do random selection, it gives me random face selection. I don't want to select faces, just random verts.

Answer (score 3):

Probably your setting is in *'face selection'* mode, as if in *'vertex selection'* mode:

[image]